# TASM mouse problems when clicked

Tags: assembly, tasm, emu8086

I'm using TASM with assembly x86.
I loaded a bmp photo for start menu , saved the coordinates for the start button.
But whenever I press it , the new game photo is loaded , but where the mouse clicked there is a hole that shows the previous photo.

Comment: Please stop vandalizing your post. You may edit it in a way that does not invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about what the mouse driver has to do to show the mouse pointer moving across the screen without leaving a trail. It has to copy the background around the mouse before displaying the mouse pointer, then draw the mouse pointer, then restore the background to get rid of the trail.

So you have to use ax=2, int 33h to "hide" the mouse pointer, then when you've loaded the new bitmap use ax=1, int 33h to show the mouse pointer again.